# Find the bounds, max and min of $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2, x<a \\ a+2, x\geq a\end{cases} \mbox{ on } [-a-1, a+1]$

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2, x<a \\ a+2, x\geq a\end{cases} \mbox{ on } [-a-1, a+1]$$

1. $-1<a\leq-\frac12$, maximum, minimum, upper and lower bounds is $a+2$ because $f(x)=a+2$ for these $a$.
2. $-\frac12<a\lt0$, maximum and upper bound is is $max((a+1)^2,a+2)$ because the function is defined on a closed interval and the maximum is one of the parabola's endpoints or the horizontal line, whichever greater. There's no minimum because for any minimum $f(x), x<a$ there is $f\left(\frac{a-x}2\right)$ which is less than $f(x)$.
3. $a\geq0$, maximum and upper bound is is $max((a+1)^2,a+2)$, minimum and lower bound is the tip of the parabola $f(0)=0$.

This doesn't quite match with the answer that says:

1. $-1<a\leq-\frac12$, minimum and maximum is $\frac32$, bounded above and below
2. $-\frac12<a\lt0$, no minimum, maximum $\frac32$, bounded above and below
3. $a\geq0$ minimum $0$, maximum $max(a^2,a+2)$.

How on earth did they get $\frac32$? I guess this is what $a+2$ when $a=-\frac12$, but $a$ can take other values on its interval. Why $a^2$ in $max(a^2,a+2)$? The highest endpoint of the parabola is $(a+1)^2$. Just looking at the graph on desmos shows that the maximum for $a=2$ is $(2+1)^2=9$, not $2^2=4$

This is the exercise 7-1(vi) from Spivak's calculus.

Comment: please note the first function is defined for $x \lt a$ and so you cannot have $(a+1)^2$. On your first point, there is nothing wrong in the way you are thinking. As the range of $a$ is finite, they have found the maximum instead of leaving it as $(a+2)$.

Comment: @MathLover but I can have $(-a-1)^2=(a+1)^2$

Comment: yes you are right on that!